# How to write pattern splices in expression quotation?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm trying to write a declaration using [*expression quotation*](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html), 
and whatever I try the compiler fails on pattern with a message like the following:

```
Parse error in pattern: $pattern
```

Here's an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, QuasiQuotes #-}
import Language.Haskell.TH

data A = A Int Int

decl :: DecsQ
decl = [d|
    instance Show A where
      show $pattern = undefined
  |]
  where
    pattern = conP (mkName "A") $ map varP $ map mkName $ ["a", "b"]
```

Answer (score 4):

The TH documentation says that:

> Note that pattern splices are not supported

More details [here](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1476)

Answer (score 2):

GHC HEAD (7.8-to-be) has improved TH support and successfully compiles your code.